# MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance equivalent in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, area

We can set the surrounding area for particular location on map in iPhone as following

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {latitude:37.09024, longitude:-95.712891};
CLLocationDistance latitudinalMeters;
latitudinalMeters =NoOfMiles * 1609.344;
CLLocationDistance longitudinalMeters;
longitudinalMeters = NoOfMiles * 1609.344;
mapViewHome.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, latitudinalMeters, longitudinalMeters);
```

Is there any equivalent method for Android?

Answer (score 15):

This code is **not** production quality. Use Chris suggestion from comments here instead: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35823607#comment4

---

This question was originally asked for Maps API v1. This answer is for v2, but can be easily changed to v1, so...

No easy way to do it.

You may want to [request this feature on gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2).

As waiting for this to be implemented on Google side can take several months, so this is what I would do:

```
private static final double ASSUMED_INIT_LATLNG_DIFF = 1.0;
private static final float ACCURACY = 0.01f;

public static LatLngBounds boundsWithCenterAndLatLngDistance(LatLng center, float latDistanceInMeters, float lngDistanceInMeters) {
    latDistanceInMeters /= 2;
    lngDistanceInMeters /= 2;
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = LatLngBounds.builder();
    float[] distance = new float[1];
    {
        boolean foundMax = false;
        double foundMinLngDiff = 0;
        double assumedLngDiff = ASSUMED_INIT_LATLNG_DIFF;
        do {
            Location.distanceBetween(center.latitude, center.longitude, center.latitude, center.longitude + assumedLngDiff, distance);
            float distanceDiff = distance[0] - lngDistanceInMeters;
            if (distanceDiff < 0) {
                if (!foundMax) {
                    foundMinLngDiff = assumedLngDiff;
                    assumedLngDiff *= 2;
                } else {
                    double tmp = assumedLngDiff;
                    assumedLngDiff += (assumedLngDiff - foundMinLngDiff) / 2;
                    foundMinLngDiff = tmp;
                }
            } else {
                assumedLngDiff -= (assumedLngDiff - foundMinLngDiff) / 2;
                foundMax = true;
            }
        } while (Math.abs(distance[0] - lngDistanceInMeters) > lngDistanceInMeters * ACCURACY);
        LatLng east = new LatLng(center.latitude, center.longitude + assumedLngDiff);
        builder.include(east);
        LatLng west = new LatLng(center.latitude, center.longitude - assumedLngDiff);
        builder.include(west);
    }
    {
        boolean foundMax = false;
        double foundMinLatDiff = 0;
        double assumedLatDiffNorth = ASSUMED_INIT_LATLNG_DIFF;
        do {
            Location.distanceBetween(center.latitude, center.longitude, center.latitude + assumedLatDiffNorth, center.longitude, distance);
            float distanceDiff = distance[0] - latDistanceInMeters;
            if (distanceDiff < 0) {
                if (!foundMax) {
                    foundMinLatDiff = assumedLatDiffNorth;
                    assumedLatDiffNorth *= 2;
                } else {
                    double tmp = assumedLatDiffNorth;
                    assumedLatDiffNorth += (assumedLatDiffNorth - foundMinLatDiff) / 2;
                    foundMinLatDiff = tmp;
                }
            } else {
                assumedLatDiffNorth -= (assumedLatDiffNorth - foundMinLatDiff) / 2;
                foundMax = true;
            }
        } while (Math.abs(distance[0] - latDistanceInMeters) > latDistanceInMeters * ACCURACY);
        LatLng north = new LatLng(center.latitude + assumedLatDiffNorth, center.longitude);
        builder.include(north);
    }
    {
        boolean foundMax = false;
        double foundMinLatDiff = 0;
        double assumedLatDiffSouth = ASSUMED_INIT_LATLNG_DIFF;
        do {
            Location.distanceBetween(center.latitude, center.longitude, center.latitude - assumedLatDiffSouth, center.longitude, distance);
            float distanceDiff = distance[0] - latDistanceInMeters;
            if (distanceDiff < 0) {
                if (!foundMax) {
                    foundMinLatDiff = assumedLatDiffSouth;
                    assumedLatDiffSouth *= 2;
                } else {
                    double tmp = assumedLatDiffSouth;
                    assumedLatDiffSouth += (assumedLatDiffSouth - foundMinLatDiff) / 2;
                    foundMinLatDiff = tmp;
                }
            } else {
                assumedLatDiffSouth -= (assumedLatDiffSouth - foundMinLatDiff) / 2;
                foundMax = true;
            }
        } while (Math.abs(distance[0] - latDistanceInMeters) > latDistanceInMeters * ACCURACY);
        LatLng south = new LatLng(center.latitude - assumedLatDiffSouth, center.longitude);
        builder.include(south);
    }
    return builder.build();
}
```

Usage:

```
LatLngBounds bounds = AndroidMapsExtensionsUtils.boundsWithCenterAndLatLngDistance(new LatLng(51.0, 19.0), 1000, 2000);
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 0));
```

Notes:

- this code has not been fully tested, may not work for edge cases
- you may want to adjust private constants to have it execute faster
- you may remove 3rd part where `LatLng south` is calculated and do it like for longitudes: this will be accurate for small values of latDistance (guessing you will not see a difference under 100km)
- code is ugly, so feel free to refactor

Comment: this code results in ANR on some devices (for example Huawei G700), trace log here: http://hastebin.com/nufokuxebi.avrasm

Comment: @Nima This code is not production quality. Use Chris suggestion from comments here instead: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5704

Comment: @MaciejGórski Yes, did that already.. but your code was interesting as well, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

While the above answer might work, it does not really look straight forward as the author already mentioned. Here is some code that works for me. Please note the code assumes the earth is a perfect sphere.

```
double latspan = (latMeters/111325);
double longspan = (longMeters/111325)*(1/ Math.cos(Math.toRadians(location.latitude))); 

LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(
    new LatLng(location.latitude-latspan, location.longitude-longspan),
    new LatLng(location.latitude+latspan, location.longitude+longspan));
```

Comment: Simple, concise and good enough for most if not all applications.  Thanks

Comment: What is the number 111325 based off of?

Comment: Much better answer if this would explain what 111325 is.