# Google Maps trace my location

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have GoogleMaps V2 in android.
How can I center the map at my location and trace my location automatically, that if I moved, the map will set my new location in the center of the map. And how can I make that the circle of the accuracy will be in full size (all over the control)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To track current location use [LocationClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html). More info here: http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

After you receive `Location` update from it, you may want to call `GoogleMap.animateCamera` to center on it.

To zoom on the circle, you need to know its size. `Location.getAccuracy` will tell you that. Then you may use [this ugly function of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224671/mkcoordinateregionmakewithdistance-equvivalent-in-android/16417396#16417396) to calculate `LatLngBounds` from center point and radius in meters, which can be put into `animateCamera` for your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

let's assume that the declared variable is `GoogleMap mMap;`

add these to your `mMap` :

```
mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

after that, there will be a button at the top right position of your map, similar with the ones inside the google Maps application, press it, and your movement will be followed.

what do you mean with full size accuracy circle? the smaller the circle, the better your location accuracy.

Regards,

Reid

Comment: First, can I do this automatically without any button?
Second, google maps show blue circle in the map (this circle is the accuracy of the location) I want that the map will zoom in into that circle and show it in zoom that will cause this circle to saw in the full size of the fragment